# strcmp output with positive value

Tags: c++, strcmp

I read the description of strcmp it said "Tests the strings for equality. Returns a negative number if string1 is less than string2, returns zero if the two strings are equal, and returns a positive number is string1 is greater than string2" from http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/strcmp.html. however, I ran into a program that gives me positive number instead of negative number. Can anyone explain why it is positive instead of negative output?

```
using namespace std;

int f(int n) {
if (n < 0) {
    return -1;
} else if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char a[10];
char b[10];
int n;

strcpy(a, "4");
strcpy(b, "345");

n = strcmp(a, b);
cout << f(n) << endl;
}
```

Comment: If the point of `f()` just to confuse matters? Anyway, `"4"` is lexicographically greater than "345".

Comment: Oh just want to make it more simple

Comment: Really? Why not just print out `n`?

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. "345" comes before "4", just like "abc" would come before "b" in a dictionary. If you want to compare the numbers, you'd have to parse the strings first.

Comment: lexicographically? I need to look up this word, but thanks

Comment: thanks for the dictionary case, I got it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` compares characters, not numerical values. "4" is greater than "345" lexicographically, hence the positive result.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!